# Question marks returned in the string values which are not displayed in the dataset

Tags: sql-server, string, unicode, replace, sqldatatypes

I have an issue with some of the string values. The source table was populated from Excel via SSIS.

Once update destination tables with data from import table I see some records have '??' signs in some fields.

The code below actually resolves the issue. But the problem is that once I do the same on actual table the issue is not going away and question marks still present.

```
drop table #t

create table #t (email nvarchar(1000) null)
insert into #t values ( '​​vwallace@charlott​enc.gov​' ) 
select * from #t

update #t 
set email =  REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(email,''))),'?','')
select * from #t
   -- > once this is done on actual table I'm still getting value like this 
"??vwallace@charlott?enc.gov?"
```

For testing purposes I used the queries below

```
SELECT CAST(email as varbinary(max)) FROM #t
```

output is

0x3F003F007600770061006C006C00610063006500400063006800610072006C006F00740074003F0065006E0063002E0067006F0076003F00

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; Declare @i int, @p int = 0, @e nvarchar(1000); SELECT @e = email from #t; SET @i = LEN(@e); WHILE @p<@i BEGIN Set @p += 1; PRINT Substring(@e, @p, 1); END
```

?   ?   v   w   a   l   l   a   c   e   @   c   h   a   r   l   o   t   t   ?   e   n   c   .   g   o   v   ?

Comment: Possibly, the actual problematic characters are not question marks, but something else (which your SQL client *displays* as `?`).

Comment: Try running the following select against your table:  `select email, ASCII(email) as AsciiValue from #t`. If the value returned by ASCII() is less than 32 or greater than 127, you've got bad data in the email string.

Comment: Hi @LaughingVergil I ran the query you suggested it returned 63. select ASCII(email) from #t

Comment: This implies that the question marks are display glitches, not real changes in the string. Try running this query: `SET NOCOUNT ON; Declare @i int, @p int = 0, @e nvarchar(1000); SELECT @e = email from #vt; SET @i = LEN(@e);
WHILE @p<@i BEGIN
Set @p += 1; PRINT Substring(@e, @p, 1);
END
` and check each character in the output. If they exactly match the expected email address, then the problem is a display/hardware/network issue, probably the latter.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Just did it and it printed 4 actual question marks 2 at the  very beginning and 2 in the middle. So, somehow it' does contain question marks :)

Comment: Would be interesting to see the output of `select cast(email as varbinary(max))` added to the question. Excel is known to trash Unicode characters when saving to delimited text files (sometimes TSV, but especially CSV) so I suspect that the question marks are where Unicode characters used to be in the original data.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Hi, I've ran the query and posted the output in my question above.

Comment: So those question marks are actually in the SQL data (varbinary `0x3f00` == U+003F == `?`). I'd be looking more closely at your Excel-SSIS process to see how it's getting clobbered.

Comment: A would not agree with this @AlwaysLearning. I also copied the value directly from Excel file and it also displays "?" when running this select '​​vwallace@charlott​enc.gov​'